# Puppeteer | Protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Printing failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, jsreport

I use jsreport-core in my node project to generate PDF or XLSX files, to generate PDF I use the library jsreport-chrome-pdf that use puppeteer for rendering, and handlebars for HTML templating.

For small HTML tables without a lot of data, the rendering is really fast on every side but when I need to render really huge tables (around 1400 pages, 7 columns / ~60 rows per page) I get a timeout after 60s. The problem is when I increase this timeout; I get this new error (the title) and I don't understand what that means, I think it is because puppeteer can't handle the processing of all the data but I wanted to know if there was a solution.

I tried different versions of jsreport-core and jsreport-chrome-pdf but no changes on this side. I also tried to delete elements of my template (CSS, helpers, conditions, etc.) to see if this was the problem but no changes either.

Precisions : My template doesn't have images or other heavy elements, it's just a lot of plain text in huge tables.

This is my configurations of both packages :

- jsreport-core :

```js
const jsreport = require('@jsreport/jsreport-core')({
    allowLocalFilesAccess: true,
    reportTimeout: 600000,
    templatingEngines: { timeout: 600000 },
    sandbox: { cache: { max: 500 } },
    workers: { numberOfWorkers: 5 }
});
```

- jsreport-chrome-pdf :

```js
    .use(require('@jsreport/jsreport-chrome-pdf')({
        timeout: 600000,
        launchOptions: {
            headless: true,
            args: [
                '--disable-gl-drawing-for-tests',
                '--headless',
                '--enable-webgl',
                '--hide-scrollbars',
                '--mute-audio',
                '--use-gl=swiftshader',
                '--disable-canvas-aa',
                '--disable-2d-canvas-clip-aa',
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--full-memory-crash-report',
                '--unlimited-storage'
            ]
        }
    }))
```

I tried to optimise these as much as I could to improve the performance but I think the problem is somewhere else.

I precise : I also tried to generate an HTML file directly, and no problem there, data are entirely shown and the generation take ~500ms.

The full error, if it can be useful :

```
ProtocolError: Protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Printing failed
    at C:\dev\xplanet\srv\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:286:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (C:\dev\xplanet\srv\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:282:16)
    at Page.createPDFStream (C:\dev\xplanet\srv\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:1963:85)
    at Page.pdf (C:\dev\xplanet\srv\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:1993:37)
    at C:\dev\xplanet\srv\node_modules\@jsreport\jsreport-chrome-pdf\lib\conversion.js:363:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async C:\dev\xplanet\srv\node_modules\@jsreport\jsreport-chrome-pdf\lib\conversion.js:404:22
```

Comment: Yes chrome has issues with long tables. Its slow and can crash on OOM. Did you try the latest packages released this week? There is an updated chrome binary and maybe it gets faster for you.

Comment: Yes, updated ! But unfortunately there are no improvements for my case...

Comment: @Myoboku  Did you find the solution related to this issue

Comment: @JanBlaha I also tried new version but still getting this error

Comment: Please share the html on which chrome fails. (maybe better to ask on our forum)

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: @paradox sorry I didn't, seems like we can't get past the limits of the engine